# Update key in Firebase Realtime Database and accessing sub-keys

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity in which I am allowing the user to change his UserPIN(immediate key under Attendance_Records table), and I have read that there is no other way to update Firebase Realtime Database other than removing and adding the data with updation again. My problem is I have to update a table whose key I want to update but it has multiple sub-keys and a lot of data. How can I access the sub-keys and store them? Won't the data updation take a lot of time? Is there any other way I am missing?

[image: My Table]

**EDIT**

I have achieved the level where I am able to retrieve the data from the Attendance_Records table by using:

```
rootRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance_Records").child(carriedmPIN);

    newRefAttTable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attendance_Records");

    attRec = new Attendance_Records();
```

then

```
private void changeAttTable(){
    Log.d("abcd","changeAttTable() reached");

    rootRefAttTable.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                for(DataSnapshot yearsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    yearKey = yearsnap.getKey();
                    Log.d("abcd","yearKey is: "+yearKey);

                    monthkeyRef = rootRefAttTable.child(yearKey);
                    monthkeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                for(DataSnapshot monthsnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    monthKey = monthsnap.getKey();

                                    datekeyRef = monthkeyRef.child(monthKey);
                                    datekeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                                for(DataSnapshot datesnap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                    dateKey = datesnap.getKey();


                                                    date = datesnap.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                                                    enteryDate = datesnap.child("entryDate").getValue(String.class);
                                                    inTime = datesnap.child("inTime").getValue(String.class);
                                                    month = datesnap.child("month").getValue(String.class);
                                                    myID = datesnap.child("myID").getValue(String.class);
                                                    outTime = datesnap.child("outTime").getValue(String.class);
                                                    status = datesnap.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                                                    year = datesnap.child("year").getValue(String.class);

                                                    addDataAttTable();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void getValuesAtt(){
    Log.d("abcd","getValuesAtt() reached");

    attRec.setYear(year);
    attRec.setMonth(month);
    attRec.setMyID(myID);
    attRec.setEntryDate(enteryDate);
    attRec.setStatus(status);
    attRec.setOutTime(outTime);
    attRec.setInTime(inTime);
    attRec.setDate(date);
}

private void addDataAttTable(){
    Log.d("abcd","addDataAttTable() reached");

    getValuesAtt();
    newRefAttTable.child(carriedmPIN).removeValue();
    newRefAttTable.child(enterednewmpin).child(yearKey).child(monthKey).child(dateKey).setValue(attRec);
}
```

But, the addition to database is not in the way it was: [image: Before] [image: After]

Sorry about the before updation image.
After updation(123450 to 123459), the months 3 and 4 are joined together, and for now I don't have 2 years(2018 and 2019 suppose) else I think they would also have joined. How can I correct this?

Comment: Which particular key you want to be renamed?

Comment: @AlexMamo 123452 is the key i want to rename

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried some code and have edited my question, please check that

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please tell fast... I am on a deadline :/

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do. Firebase doesn't have the concept of "renaming" a part of the path via update. Instead you will have to completely remove the existing node and recreate it. It will be done in very less time so you won't be notified that you have removed and added a whole new node.

step 1: Copy the existing object by retrieving it as a model.

step 2: Create a new child with your desired updated name.

step 3: Assign values for newly created child using `ref.setValue(model);`

step 4: Remove old child by using `ref.removeValue();` or `ref.setValue(null);`

Comment: Yes I know that and hence going in the same direction but I am having difficulty in that, please refer to the Edits I have made